# $x \in A \Delta (B \Delta C)$ iff $x$ belongs to an odd number of $A$, $B$, $C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> The *symmetric difference* $A \Delta B$ of $A$ and $B$ is defined to be $(A - B) \cup (B - A)$. (That is, it is the set of elements that belong to one of $A$ and $B$ but not both.) Write out a truth table to show that the operation $\Delta$ is associative. Show that $x$ belongs to $A \Delta (B \Delta C)$ if and only if $x$ belongs to an odd number of the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ and use this observation to give a second proof that $\Delta$ is associative.

Now, I wrote out the truth table, that was relatively straightforward. It's showing the iff criterion for $A \Delta (B \Delta C)$ in the fashion intended by the problem setter that's tripping me. Sure, the iff criterion follows from reading off the truth table, but that's casework and I can't help but feel there's a more "correct"/elegant way of seeing it. Let me spell out my thoughts.

We have$$B \Delta C = (B - C) \cup (C - B).$$Then$$A \Delta (B \Delta C) = (A - ((B - C) \cup (C - B))) \cup (((B - C) \cup (C - B)) - A).$$What can we say about $A - ((B - C) \cup (C - B))$? Well, I showed in a previous problem that$$X - (Y \cup Z) = (X - Y) \cap (X - Z).$$So I can write$$A - ((B - C) \cup (C - B)) = (A - (B - C)) \cap (A - (C - B)).$$Also, it is not too hard to see that$$(X \cup Y) - Z = (X -Z) \cup (Y - Z),$$so$$((B - C) \cup (C - B)) - A = ((B - C) - A) \cup ((C - B) - A).$$So we have$$\begin{align*}
A \Delta (B \Delta C) & = (A - ((B - C) \cup (C - B))) \cup (((B - C) \cup (C - B)) - A) \\ & = ((A - (B - C)) \cap (A - (C - B))) \cup (((B - C) - A) \cup ((C - B) - A)).\end{align*}$$However, I'm stuck at this point... presuming that expanding out is the intended first step and I'm not totally going up the wrong alley... and don't know how to see the iff criterion. Could someone give me a hint? I would prefer a conceptual, elegant way to see the iff criterion as opposed to deferring to the casework of the truth table.

**Edit:** Anurag A wrote the following.

> Perhaps a proof by contradiction would be easier to write. Suppose $x \in A \Delta (B \Delta C)$ and it belongs to an **even number** of the sets among $A,B$ and $C$. So either $x$ is in none of these sets (since $0$ is an even number) or $x$ is in exactly two of the  sets among $A,B$ and $C$. The $0$ case is easy because then $x \not\in  A \Delta (B \Delta C)$.
>
> Case (1): $x \in A \, \wedge \, x \in B \, \wedge \, x \not\in C$ (same idea will work if we switch $B$ and $C$). Then $x \in A$ and $x \in B \Delta C$. But then $x \in A \cap (B \Delta C)$., which means $x \not \in  A \Delta (B \Delta C)$, a contradiction.
>
> Now take 
>   Case(2) : $x \not\in A \, \wedge \, x \in B \, \wedge \, x \in C$ and proceed.

This is casework, and I've already come up with this solution myself. I would prefer a more conceptual (i.e. why does this really work), elegant solution if possible, or perhaps an explanation that I'm shooting for something that really isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define the characteristic function of a set $A$ as

$
\chi_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $x\in A$}\\
0, & \text{if $x\notin A$}.
\end{cases}$

Now

$x\in A\Delta(B\Delta C)\iff \chi_{A\Delta(B\Delta C)}=1\iff \chi_A(x)+\chi_{B\Delta C}(x)-2\chi_{A\cap(B\Delta C)}(x)=1\iff \chi_A(x)+\chi_{B}(x)+\chi_ C(x)-2\chi_A(x)\chi_B(x)-2\chi_A(x)\chi_{(B\Delta C)}(x)=1\iff \chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)+\chi_C(x)\equiv1\mod 2.$

Hence $x\in A\Delta(B\Delta C)\iff x\  \text {belongs to an odd number of sets}A,B,C.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Perhaps a proof by contradiction would be easier to write. Suppose $x \in A \Delta (B \Delta C)$ and it belongs to an **even number** of the sets among $A,B$ and $C$. So either $x$ is in none of these sets (since $0$ is an even number) or $x$ is in exactly two of the  sets among $A,B$ and $C$. The $0$ case is easy because then $x \not\in  A \Delta (B \Delta C)$.

Case (1): $x \in A \, \wedge \, x \in B \, \wedge \, x \not\in C$ (same idea will work if we switch $B$ and $C$). Then $x \in A$ and $x \in B \Delta C$. But then $x \in A \cap (B \Delta C)$., which means $x \not \in  A \Delta (B \Delta C)$, a contradiction.

Now take 
Case(2) : $x \not\in A \, \wedge \, x \in B \, \wedge \, x \in C$ and proceed.

Comment: @user469827 I am not sure if I understand your point when you say "more conceptual" or "why it really works". Isn't a proof supposed to justify why it works?

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric difference corresponds to the XOR (modulo 2 sum) of the [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the sets involved. But modulo 2 sum is just another name for parity, and so the parity of the number of sets containing a given element determines if it is in the combined symmetric difference of any finite number of sets.